# Help with method of characteristics question.

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the partial differential equation,
$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial t} = (z-1)\left(kF - d \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\right) $$
where $k$ and $d$ are constants greater then $0$, and $t>0$.

The other thing I know is that $F(z,t)$ is a moment generating function, so I guess an initial condition is $F(0,t)=1$.
Partial differential equations aren't my strong point, and I have looked around for how to solve this online, but even though I think I can find some characteristics, I can't find a solution. I'm not sure my characteristics are right (different sources set them up differently), and I don't know how to use the initial condition.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t}=(z-1)\left(kF-d\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z}\right)$

$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t}+d(z-1)\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z}=k(z-1)F$

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dt}{ds}=1$ , letting $t(0)=0$ , we have $t=s$

$\dfrac{dz}{ds}=d(z-1)$ , we have $z=z_0e^{ds}+1=z_0e^{dt}+1$

$\dfrac{dF}{ds}=k(z-1)=kz_0e^{ds}$ , we have $F(z,t)=\dfrac{kz_0e^{ds}}{d}+f(z_0)=\dfrac{k(z-1)}{d}+f((z-1)e^{-dt})$

$F(0,t)=1$ :

$-\dfrac{k}{d}+f(-e^{-dt})=1$

$f(-e^{-dt})=\dfrac{k}{d}+1$

$f(t)=\dfrac{k}{d}+1$

$\therefore F(z,t)=\dfrac{k(z-1)}{d}+\dfrac{k}{d}+1=\dfrac{kz}{d}+1$